# How to clean the characters in a string in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the problem: I have an array with x element, each elements a has character , I need clean one to one for what each element, end without character.

```
var dale = [".algo,", 'otro;', "two:", ", perfecto", "nada,", "bueno ,", "hola .", ". kcoy;", ", koko:", "noc'", " 'nocto", "lolo...", "...lola", "(jose", "luis)", "maria]", "[uranga", "signo?", "¿preg", "oki!", "¡com"];

var patterns = [".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "...", "(", ")", "[", "]", "?", "¿", "!", "¡" ];

var newDale = [];
//SOLUTIONS WRONG:
for ( var i=0; i<dale.length;i++){
  for ( var x=0; x<patterns.length;x++){
    if (dale[i].search(patterns[i])){
      newDale.push(dale[i].replace(/patterns[i]/, ""));
    }
  }
}

console.log(newDale);

//OUTPUT CLEAN 

["algo", 'otro', "two", "perfecto", "nada", "bueno", "hola", "kcoy", "koko", "noc", " 'nocto", "lolo", "lola", "jose", "luis", "maria", "uranga", "signo", "preg", "oki", "com"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a `RegExp` object to do some replacing on the strings. It looks like you want only word characters (letters), correct? Maybe something like:

```
for (var i=0; i < dale.length; i++){
    newDale.push(dale[i].replace(/\W/g, ""));
}
```

References:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp (\W is non-word character, g modifier is global)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
var dale = [".algo,", 'otro;', "two:", ", perfecto", "nada,", "bueno ,", "hola .", ". kcoy;", ", koko:", "noc'", " 'nocto", "lolo...", "...lola", "(jose", "luis)", "maria]", "[uranga", "signo?", "¿preg", "oki!", "¡com"];

for (var i = 0; i < dale.length; i++) {
    console.log(dale[i].replace(/[.,;:;()\[\]?¿!¡ ']/g, ""));
}
```